# F# using the .[] operator as a function

Tags: arrays, f#, operators

F# allows most operators to be treated as functions. For example:

```
let f = (+)
f 1 2 // <- 3
```

However, I'm not sure if it's possible to make this same syntax work with the index operator (`.[...]`).

I've tried:

```
let f = (.[])
f [| 1 |] 0
```

> None of the types 'int [], int' support the operator '.[]' (using external F# compiler)

And:

```
let f = (.[])
f  0 [| 1 |]
```

> None of the types 'int, 'a []' support the operator '.[]' (using external F# compiler)

My guess is that `.[...]` is not actually an operator, but a special built-in syntax that cannot be used in a functional way, but maybe I'm missing something. Is it possible to use the operator index in the same way you normally use a function like [`Array.get`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.get%5b't%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d)?

Comment: No, that's what `Array.get` is for - or rather `Array.item` now, which has the correct order of parameters for partial application in pipe chains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have a great answer, but I do have one potentially useful observation. When you try defining something like this:

```
let (.[,]) v1 v2 = v1 + v2
```

You get an error message saying:

> error FS0035: This construct is deprecated: The treatment of this operator is now handled directly by the F# compiler and its meaning cannot be redefined

I think it used to be the case that indexing was done using actual operators (I seem to recall that might have been the case, but googling for that is impossible), but as the error message suggests, this is probably now done differently. I'm not sure why this does not apply to `.[]` though!

These [funky operator names](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/search?q=funky_operator_name&unscoped_q=funky_operator_name) appear in a couple of places in the [F# compiler source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/tests/fsharpqa/Source/Misc/E_productioncoverage03.fs).

Comment: Yes, that does shed some light on the situation. `.[]` seems to be treated a special case.